# Compare elements and make new column

Tags: r

I want to compare the i and i+1 elements of second column(Close price), and if `i<i+1` place 1 in third column. But i have no idea how to do this.

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("GOOG",src="yahoo")
data<-last(GOOG,40)
newdata<-data.frame(data[,4])
newdata
```

Comment: Question is not very clear, maybe try this example: `x <- 1:10; xdf <- data.frame(x=x, x_lag=dplyr::lag(x)); xdf$compare <- xdf$x == xdf$x_lag`

Comment: @zx8754 should it not be `xdf$x < xdf$x_lag` ?

Comment: @Tensibai yes, comparison logic was added after edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
newdata$closePrice = c((diff(newdata[,1])<0)*1,0)
```

Explanation:

`diff(newdata[,1])` will return the difference of rows `i+1` and `i`
The `<0` will give a true or false array that can be converted to 1s or 0s
Since the result will be one element short, concatenate a 0 at the end

Comment: FWIW, the `*1` is unnecessary as the concatenation with a number will coerce logical to integer, i.e: `c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,0)` give `[1] 1 0 1 0`

Answer (score 2):

Using [dplyr lead/lag](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html) function:

```
library(dplyr)

#dummy data
set.seed(123)
mydf <- data.frame(price = runif(5))

#result
mydf %>% 
  mutate(price_lead = lead(price),
         compare = ifelse(price < price_lead, 1, 0))

#output
#       price price_lead compare
# 1 0.2875775  0.7883051       1
# 2 0.7883051  0.4089769       0
# 3 0.4089769  0.8830174       1
# 4 0.8830174  0.9404673       1
# 5 0.9404673         NA      NA
```